# Eclipse Plugin Dev - Creating and updating custom markers as files are edited

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an Eclipse plugin which uses custom textmarker annotations. There are plenty of examples out there which explain how to create and delete such markers and I have this all working fine from my own event handlers (when the user clicks a 'refresh' menu item).

However, I cannot work out how to hook the Java editor such that I can do this automatically. I would like all open Java editors to call my code at the same time that it invokes the Java compiler / spell checker / etc. so that I can add and update my annotations then.

How do I do this, and can it be done without creating my own builder? I'd prefer that the user does not have to add a new builder themselves.

Thanks very much

-Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to this is probably to add a new JDT Compilation Participant - see the extension point `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems to be exactly what I want. However, I am having trouble using it.

EDIT: Wow stack overflow's comment system is particularly unhelpful. I don't appear to be able to add anything useful to this comment due to the size restrictions :/

Comment: OK, I give up with trying to format code blocks into a question edit. You answered my question nicely (it's a separate problem getting it to work!) so I'll mark this as accepted and open another if I can't get it to work. Thanks again.